# Extract Map Value to List in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map as below in Flutter/Dart.

```
Map currencyMap = {status: Success, currency: [{id: 1, code: AFN, currency: Afghan afghani, rate: 0.25}, {id: 2, code: EUR, currency: European euro, rate: 0.25}, {id: 3, code: CFA, currency: Franc CFA, rate: 0.25}]}
```

How do i extract just the codes to a list like below.

```
currencyList = [AFN, EUR, CFA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is a more `better` version (**using a map**) in just `one` line.

```
List<dynamic> currencyList = currencyMap["currency"].map((entry) => entry["code"]).toList();
print(currencyList);
```

Try this - **old version using a loop**

```
void main() {

  List currencyList = [];
  Map currencyMap = {
    "status": "Success",
    "currency": [{
        "id": "1",
        "code": "AFN",
        "currency": "Afghan afghani",
        "rate": "0.25"
    }, {
        "id ": "2",
        "code": "EUR",
        "currency": "European euro",
        "rate ": "0.25"
    }]
  };
  
  for(var currency in currencyMap["currency"]) {
     currencyList.add(currency["code"]);
  }
   
  print(currencyList);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. The updated version with just one line of code worked best for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
List currency = currencyMap["currency"] as List

List currencyList = currency?.map((value)=> {
  return value["code"]
}).toList();
```